# Maximum number of VPN Tunnels on Linksys BEFSX41?

Tags: router, vpn

The subject line is pretty much it. Is there a maximum number of VPN tunnels I can set up into a single Linksys BEFSX41? Right now we have one, but need a second for sure, and possibly more in the future. I guess an assumption I'm making here is that you can even have more than one.

For that matter, has anyone set up more than one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [router data sheet](http://homedownloads.cisco.com/downloads/datasheet/BEFSX41v2_ds.pdf) states the [BEFSX41](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/wireless/lbc/BEFSX41) supports up to two simultaneous 
VPN tunnels.

Comment: Don't know how I missed this... Thank you!